# como colocar uma classe sendo o id de outra classe em java JPA

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jpa-2.0

Olá,

Eu estou com um problema em como colocar uma classe sendo o id de outra classe em java JPA.

Eu criei a classe Teacher e a classe Acronym, ao colocar a classe Acronym como id da classe Teacher tenho um problema, pois na base de dados aparece um numero hexadecimal e eu queria que aparecesse a String com o acrônimo.

A classe Acronym

```
public class Acronym implements ValueObject, Comparable<Acronym>  {

    private String description;


    public Acronym(String description) {
        if (StringPredicates.isNullOrEmpty(description)||!validAcronym(description)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "acronym description should neither be null nor empty and must be valid");
        }
        // TODO validate invariants,
        // expression
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String acronym() {
        return this.description;
    }

    protected boolean validAcronym(String description){
        if (description.matches(".*\\d+.*")){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Acronym o) {
        return description.compareTo(o.description);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Esta é a classe Teacher

```
@Entity
public class Teacher implements AggregateRoot<Acronym> {
    @Id
    private Acronym acronym;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private TaxNumber taxNumber;

    /**
     * cascade = CascadeType.NONE as the systemUser is part of another aggregate
     */
    @OneToOne()
    private SystemUser systemUser;


    protected  Teacher() {}
    public Teacher(SystemUser user, Acronym acronym,TaxNumber taxNumber){
        if (acronym == null || user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.systemUser = user;
        this.acronym = acronym;
        this.taxNumber=taxNumber;
    }


    public SystemUser user() {
        return this.systemUser;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        return DomainEntities.areEqual(this, o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return DomainEntities.hashCode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sameAs(final Object other) {
        return DomainEntities.areEqual(this, other);
    }

    public Acronym acronym() {
        return identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Acronym identity() {
        return this.acronym;
    }

    public TeacherDTO toDTO() {
        return new TeacherDTO(acronym.acronym(), taxNumber.taxNumber());
    }


    public TaxNumber taxNumber(){
        return taxNumber;
    }
}
```

Alguém consegue dizer como faço para na base de dados não aparecer um numero hexadecimal.
Obrigado

Comment: Reparei que você está usando conceitos de DDD em código. Tenho um [repositório](https://github.com/mauriciobuffon/jakartaee-poc.git) no qual misturo alguns conceitos de DDD com JPA. Com sorte, pode lhe ser útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anote a classe `Acronym` com `@Embeddable` e implemente `Serializable`.

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Acronym implements Serializable {
  private String description;

  protected Acronym() {
  }

  public Acronym(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Na classe `Teacher` use `EmbeddedId`.

```java
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Teacher {
  @EmbeddedId
  private Acronym acronym;

  protected Teacher() {
  }

  public Teacher(Acronym acronym) {
    this.acronym = acronym;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no mapeamento de chave primária na entidade *Teacher*.

A anotação `@Id` não pode ser usada em um tipo definido pelo usuário, como é o caso da classe *Acronym*. De acordo com a [documentação](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence/latest/index.html) (ou também [aqui](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1.html#a14827)):

> The field or property to which the Id annotation is applied should be one of the following types: any Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; String; java.util.Date; java.sql.Date; java.math.BigDecimal; java.math.BigInteger.

Portanto, para tornar a classe *Acronym* uma chave primária, usa-se a anotação `EmbeddedId` na entidade. Porém, o uso da anotação `EmbeddedId` na entidade *Teacher* exije que a classe *Acronym* seja anotada como `Embbedable`.

Além disso, é importante tomar especial atenção com a sobreposição dos métodos `Object#equals` e `Object#hashCode` nos objetos de domínio, principalmente em entidades. A implementação "padrão" normalmente considera todos os membros de uma classe. Eu não recomendo que seja feito assim para as entidades de domínio (tanto agregates quanto entities).

Conceitualmente falando, os atributos que participam da definição da identidade de uma entidade já são suficientes para distinguir unequivocamente a entidade. Portanto, somente o(s) membro(s) que forma(m) a identidade deveriam ser considerados na sobreposição.

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```java
@Embeddable
public class Acronym {

    private String description;

    /* constructors and getters omitted */

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(this.description, ((Acronym) obj).description);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.description);
        return hash;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Teacher {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Acronym acronym;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private TaxNumber taxNumber;
    @OneToOne()
    private SystemUser systemUser;

    /* constructors, getters and setters omitted */

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        /* Somente o membro this#acronym define a identidade */
        return Objects.equals(this.acronym, ((Teacher) obj).acronym);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.acronym);
        return hash;
    }
}
```